# Magento 2 - Custom Column using CASE WHEN with filter via block in admin custom module grid

Tags: magento2

How to add custom column in custom module admin grid using CASE WHEN sql operator and how to filter on it?

Currently, I can able to fetch the column with correct result but, can not able to filter it.

I fetched custom column names "sign" and concated with another column and displayed in admin grid but, filter is not working on this.

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('ex_name', ['neq' => 0]);
$collection->getSelect()->columns('(CASE WHEN main_table.operation = 1 THEN "+" ELSE "-" END) AS sign');
$this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
} 
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
$this->addColumn(
            'ex_name',
            [
                'header' => __('Points'),
                'index' => array('sign', 'ex_name'),
                'sortable'     => true,
                'type'         => 'concat',
                'separator'    => ''
            ]
        );
}
```